# Do I need express if I use React Router?

Tags: express, reactjs

I am developing an application and while exploring technologies I am curious if I have Express do I need React Router if I am going to use react. On that same point, if I am using React Router do I need express? I am unsure how that whole ecosystem works.

Comment: Based on the question title, and what you are asking in the question body, the direct answer to your question is: no, you don't *need* it. But you have not clarified on your question whether or not you are doing server-side rendering. And even then, you still don't *need* it, but Express will certainly make things a lot easier, but not necessary, and I'd argue, for certain scenario, a bit overkill.

Comment: Well that is because I dont know much about server side rendering (ssr) to know if I need it or not.

Comment: Is your app even going to be rendered on the server?

Comment: Again, I dont know server side rendering.

Comment: For simplicity sake, just write front-end code, while doing very little--develoment-wise--for the back-end. In fact, for the back-end, don't even bother writing a custom server, let alone in Express; perhaps use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to avoid dealing with creating anything unwieldy from scratch.

Comment: Another question: what have you tried so far in attempting to understand what Express even is? Or, better yet, are you trying to build anything in particular?

Comment: I am writing an application in Express, I am using RESTful routes, I am not knowledgeable in React, however its called "React Router" so its a little strange. You can pass data to it, it can change the entire page so in my "newbiness" I can wrap my head around how a React app can be used without express. Especially since you can pass data into React and it renders the DOM, so its odd.

Answer (score 4):

Express is a Node Web Server Framework.

React Router routes calls inside of your front-end code.

They perform completely separate and distinct responsibilities. You don't necessarily need one or the other but using one doesn't mean you can get rid of the other either.